# Which 2D technology is used to encode more than 1kb of data?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, image-processing, barcode

I want to encode more than 1kb of data.But i tried using datamatrix .But in datamatrix we can't encode 1kb of data.Is there any other 2D technology are there to encode more than 1kb of data?

Comment: For ECC 200 Data Matrix codes, a 96 x 96 grid or larger will store at least 1000 alphanumeric characters. A 144 x 144 grid will store about 2k characters. Your particular encoding software may not be able to encode a Data Matrix with that many characters, but it's not a limitation of the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QR codes can hold up-to 2.9 kb binary data (or up-to ~7 kb numerics only).
For more info, [click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code).

> The amount of data that can be stored in the QR Code symbol depends on
>   the datatype (mode, or input character set), version (1,...,40,
>   indicating the overall dimensions of the symbol), and error correction
>   level. The maximum storage capacities occur for 40-L symbols (version
>   40, error correction level L), and are as follows (where character
>   refers to individual values of the input mode/datatype, as indicated):

```
Numeric only    Max. 7,089 characters (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
Alphanumeric    Max. 4,296 characters (0–9, A–Z [upper-case only], space, $, %, *, +, -, ., /, :)
Binary/byte     Max. 2,953 characters (8-bit bytes) (23624 bits)
Kanji/Kana      Max. 1,817 characters
```

Answer (score 0):

At the maximum size and minimum recommended error correction level, PDF417 (ISO 15438) is capable of storing 1726 bytes of ASCII text, 1033 bytes of data or 2528 decimal numbers.